# How to solve nginx server restart issue?

Tags: laravel, nginx, cocos2d-js

Now I am using Cocos as frontend, and Laravel as backend.

And server is NGINX.
After restart NGINX server, I got this error.

[image]

[image]

Before restart server, there was no error.  How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected for the server to close all connections when it's restarted. You should use "reload" instead. Typically:

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control